# How do I stop Firefox from overrriding my home page?

Tags: firefox, homepage

I have a home page explicitly set in my options, and "Go to my home page" chosen.

But every time I open Firefox, it goes to "http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/" instead of my home page, because it wants me to download a new version.

Clicking the home button still goes to my real home page.

How do I set Firefox to always open my real home page, and never override it with anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. My launcher was useing the command:

firefox %u firefox -profilemanager -no-remote

Which was trying to open the URL "firefox", which redirected to the Mozilla site. I changed it to:

firefox -profilemanager -no-remote

And it now seems to be loading the correct home page every-time.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for posting your solution. Don't forget to accept your own answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but I think you'll have to download and install the latest version to make it stop. They probably just did that to make people update to the latest version.

Unless you've got a particular reason not to; try to update.

Comment: I do- Its an application that runs in its own profile without any menus, and behaves like a desktop application. There is no way for a user to get to any other page, since it's supposed to automatically start on the main application page.

Comment: Aha, I see! Like a "library browser"-type application? Could you request from the developer of this application to keep Firefox up-to-date? I would assume this to be a part of application maintenance, having chosen this approach. Optionally, you could contact Mozilla and explain the problem; perhaps they'll be willing to change this behavior.

Comment: I am the developer. It's a customer/order management system for our company that runs on our LAN. It's not that we can't update the browser, it's that every time a new minor release comes out, we can't have an emergency where every one of our customer service computers stops working all at once! (with chrome/menus off, there is no way to get into the application! It relies on the homepage to get to the first screen.)